# Convert a time series data to proper time steps

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, time

I have a dataset with 20331 rows and 6 columns. It's based on hourly sampled time series data.
I would like to convert this to a format that looks like [samples, timesteps, features].

I attempted the following code:

```
train.reshape((20331, 30, 6))
```

The resulting sample should have 30 timesteps and 6 features in each sample.

But I got an error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 121986 into shape
> (20331,30,6)

Do I need to do any preprocessing before doing reshaping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create data with `numpy.reshape`. It is only meant to **reshape** the underlying data.

So in your case, you are starting with 20'331 * 6 = 121'986 datapoints, and you want to arrange them into (20'331 * 30 * 6) = 3'659'580 datapoints, which is 30 times more than you started with.

What should be your data in the 2nd dimension? Think about that. Numpy can't create data out of thin air.

---

**Edit:**

If you want to have slices of 30 datapoints, you can do something like this:

```
bs = 30 # your chosen batch-size
tail = len(train) % bs # the leftover for the last batch
train_crop = train[:-tail].reshape((-1, bs, 6))
```

The last line will discard the last items so your length is divisible by your batch size. The shape of your reshape is `6` in the last, feature dimension, `bs` in the second dimension and `-1` in the first, which lets pytorch figure out the size on its own.

Comment: Thanks for helping. How can I reshape the data that I have into a suitable size that will be of shape -> [samples, timesteps, features] ? I have 6 features in total, and I would like to have 30 time steps.

Comment: you have 20'331 consecutive datapoints. If you want to have slices of 30, you get 677 slices and 21 datapoints leftovers.

Comment: Thanks Dorian, it makes sense to me now.